# Work in electric field - formula

Tags: electric-fields, work

Suppose there's a electric field generated by a charge $Q$. If I moved a charge $q$ placed at distance $r_1$ away from $Q$ to distance $r_2$, supposedly the average force acting on $q$ will be:

$F=\sqrt{F_1 F_2}=\sqrt{k \frac{Qq}{r_1^2} k \frac{Qq}{r_2^2}}=k \frac{Qq}{r_1 r_2}$ (where $F_1$ is the force acting on it at $r_1$, similarly for $F_2$).

Why do we calculate it that way, taking the square root of $F_1 F_2$?

If you calculate the work when moving the charge $q$ from $r_1$ to $r_2$ using this formula, you get the right formula ($s$ is the displacement $r_2 - r_1$)

$W=F s \cos(\alpha) = kQq(\frac{1}{r_1}-\frac{1}{r_2})$.

Answer (score 1):

The mean force ($F$) acting on charge Q will be given by :
$$
F = \frac{1}{r_1-r_2}\int_{r_1}^{r_2}{K\frac{qQ}{r^2}dr}
$$
which gives, once calculated :
$$
F = \frac{KQq}{r_1r_2}
$$

which is equivalent to calculating $\sqrt{F_1F_2}$ like you did.

For your second formula :
$$
Fs\cos(\alpha) = kQq(\frac{1}{r_1}-\frac{1}{r_2})
$$
also simplifies in
$$
F = \frac{KQq}{r_1r_2}
$$
with $\cos{\alpha} = 1$